# Refusing to create an empty archive

Tags: command-line, tar

I have a problem with this command:

```
su -c 'tar zcvf yourname.tar.gz/etc/var/'
```

[Here](http://www.content.distance-education.itt-tech.edu/cliksdmrroot/content_directory/mount1/507393/IS3440/Lab10_SLMx_Linuxsec20.pdf) is the website for my class assignment.

Some of these command do not work correctly.

Help!

Comment: Close voters: What's unclear here? (other than somebody trying to get his assignment done)  :P

Answer (score 1):

The correct command is

```
sudo su -c 'tar zcvf yourname.tar.gz /etc /var'
```

or simply

```
sudo tar zcvf yourname.tar.gz /etc /var
```

---

And you forgot the space characters in your command:

```
su -c 'tar zcvf yourname.tar.gz/etc/var/'
                               ^   ^-- Missing SPACE
                                -- Missing SPACE
```

---

Your PDF has a very bad quality, it seems like an OCR output. You shouldn't copy and paste the commands. And the PDF is not written for Ubuntu, therefore some commands and procedures may be wrong.

Comment: @MayaKoonKoon As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey ☑ at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)